# if(objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &Key)) return true for nil object

Tags: ios, objective-c

How can I test that `objc_getAssociatedObject` is `nil`? The following says element is not `nil` but the associated object has never been set before nor been accessed.

```
static char orderedElementKey = 11;

if (objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &orderedElementKey) != nil)
{
    NSLog(@"element is not nil");
    return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &orderedElementKey);
}
NSLog(@"elelement was nil !");
```

Comment: What is the object being returned?

Comment: NSStringFromClass print (null)

Comment: It works for me, what is orderedElementKey?

Comment: static char orderedElementKey = 11;

Comment: okay now it's working I don't know why

Comment: Note that the "11" here is unused by the system. `objc_getAssociatedObject` does not care what the value is, only the address. Setting it to a value, especially a non-zero value, can be confusing because it suggests the value actually means something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
static char orderedElementKey = 11;
//objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &orderedElementKey, @"value", OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN);

if (objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &orderedElementKey) != nil)
{
    NSLog(@"Element: %@", objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &orderedElementKey));
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"element nil !");
}
```

prints "Element nil !" while removing the comment on `objc_setAssociatedObject()` prints "Element: value". How is your code different?

Comment: thank but it suddenly started to work as expected, I have no idea why  it failed to return nil.